# What is @JsonProperty equivalent in Node.js (or JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I want to rename json objects' keys in Node.js(or JavaScript). Like how we use @JsonProperty to rename in java is there something equivalent in JavaScript to do the same?

I wrote the following code in java to change the keys' name(from caps to camel case) of a json object.

```
public class Rename {
    @JsonProperty("STUDENT_ID")
    private String studentId;
    @JsonProperty("STUDENT_NAME")
    private String studentName;

    public String getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + 
                 "\"studentId\":\"" + studentId + '\"' +
                 ", \"studentName\":\"" + studentName + '\"' +
               '}';
    }

}
```

I want to do the same in Node.js. Is there any annotation or any methods available to do it?

This is what I have done till now:

```
class Rename {
    studentId = '';
    studentName = '';

    getStudentId = function() {
        return studentId;
    }

    setStudentId = function(studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    getStudentName = function() {
        return studentName;
    }

    setStudentName = function(studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    // I'm not sure how to write toString() function
}

const info = require('./file.json')
info.forEach(node => {
    let n = node;
    let obj = new Rename();
    // I am confused how to call toString()
}
```

file.json looks like :

```
[
  {
    "STUDENT_ID": "1",
    "STUDENT_NAME" "abc"
  },
  {
    "STUDENT_ID": "2",
    "STUDENT_NAME" "xyz"
  }
]
```

I want the output to be:

```
[
  {
    "studentId": "1",
    "studentName" "abc"
  },
  {
    "studentId": "2",
    "studentName" "xyz"
  }
]
```

Comment: I don't know if I am getting your question corectly but still. You can access all object keys as array with Object,keys(objectName) and then you can map through them and create new object with renamed keys. If you could post an example of what you want it may help to provide better answer.

Comment: annotation, no, methods, yes - code is the method

Comment: @Mehrwarz I have edited my question as required. I had used map() method on json object for renaming but I want to do it using a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent baked into JavaScript.

The `@JsonProperty` comes from [the Jackson library](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html), so it is not even part of Java. It is a convenience for the serialiser/deserialiser to rename a property.

A custom function can be defined that does renaming of properties:

```js
const renamer = (mappings, obj) => 
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([key, value]) => [mappings.get(key) ?? key, value])
  );


const student = {
    studentId: "123",
    studentName: "Fred"
};

const studentMappings = new Map()
  .set("studentId", "STUDENT_ID")
  .set("studentName", "STUDENT_NAME");

const renamed = renamer(studentMappings, student);
console.log(renamed);
```

And with it a serialiser/deserialiser pair can be created for a data type:

```js
const renamer = (mappings, obj) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([key, value]) => [mappings.get(key) ?? key, value])
  );

const invertMap = map =>
  new Map(Array.from(map, ([k, v]) => [v, k]));

const dataHandler = mappings => ({
  serialiser: obj =>
    JSON.stringify(renamer(mappings, obj)),
  deserialiser: json =>
    renamer(invertMap(mappings), JSON.parse(json))
});


const student = {
  studentId: "123",
  studentName: "Fred"
};

const studentMappings = new Map()
  .set("studentId", "STUDENT_ID")
  .set("studentName", "STUDENT_NAME");

const studentDataHandler = dataHandler(studentMappings);

const serialised = studentDataHandler.serialiser(student);
console.log("serialised:", serialised);
console.log("deserialised:", studentDataHandler.deserialiser(serialised));
```

```css
.as-console.wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

For only serialisation, this can be achieved closer to Jackson's behaviour by providing a custom [`Object#toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) method which will automatically be called when serialising with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

A generic function can be defined with the purpose to be re-used on many objects. This function can look up the mappings from the object instance using a known [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) and proceed with the renaming:

```js
const renamer = (mappings, obj) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([key, value]) => [mappings.get(key) ?? key, value])
  );

function implicitRename() {
  const mappings = this[Symbol.for("serialisationMappings")] ?? new Map();
  
  return renamer(mappings, this);
}


const studentMappings = new Map()
  .set("studentId", "STUDENT_ID")
  .set("studentName", "STUDENT_NAME");
  
const student = {
  studentId: "123",
  studentName: "Fred",
  [Symbol.for("serialisationMappings")]: studentMappings,
  toJSON: implicitRename
};

class StudentClass {
  get [Symbol.for("serialisationMappings")]() {
    return studentMappings;
  }
  
  constructor(id, name) {
    this.studentId = id;
    this.studentName = name;
  }
  
  toJSON() {
    return implicitRename.call(this);
  }
}

const serialisedPlainObject = JSON.stringify(student);
console.log("serialised plain object:", serialisedPlainObject);

const studentInstance = new StudentClass("321", "Barney");
const serialisedClassInstance = JSON.stringify(studentInstance);
console.log("serialised class instance object:", serialisedClassInstance);
```

```css
.as-console.wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

As can bee seen, this can work on classes and plain objects. However, it is one-way only: when serialising to JSON. The conversion from JSON to an object (when using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)) cannot be done generically because the JSON result does not provide information about the type nor which mappings to use.

Something similar to `dataHandler` implementation above can be used if a function is defined to deserialise each type.

For classes specifically, a static `fromJSON()` method can be provided which will know what the mappings are. However, the implementation would need to vary based on the object. For example, for the `StudentClass` it could look like this but other classes might need other ways to be instantiated (from a factory method or otherwise):

```javascript
class StudentClass{
  /* ... */
  static fromJSON(json) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(json);
    
    return new StudentClass(obj.STUDENT_ID, obj.STUDENT_NAME);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped a lot in solving my problem.
Is the following method also valid? (i just wrote it based on what you explained) 
'
var newData = jsonobj.map({ STUDENT_ID: studentId,
                                               STUDENT_NAME: studentName
                                            }) => ({
                                                   studentId,
                                                   studentName}));

Comment: @Renee yes, that would work. However, it only works for one type of data and only in one way. You asked about `@JsonProperty` hence I tried to give you as a generic solution as possible.