# Equivalent of [JsonPropertyName] from C# in TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, json-deserialization

I need to deserialize some JSON response to my class defined in Angular. Let's give example class:

```
export class ChatHubInfo {
  hubUrl: string = undefined!
  accessToken: string = undefined!
}
```

But the JSON response looks like:

```
{
   "hub_url": "https://localhost:8080/",
   "access_token": "v4.public.eY..."
}
```

So while deserializing I want to map `hub_url` to `hubUrl` and so on. It's easy to do in C# by using `[JsonPropertyName]` attribute, but I can't find equivalent in Angular.

Or maybe its okay to have properties names like 'hub_url_ etc?

Comment: Related:  [What is @JsonProperty equivalent in Node.js (or JavaScript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71732542)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could go over the response and replace all characters after a underscore with its capitalized version and remove the underscore on the fly, basically a snake-to-camel-case function:

```
function snakeToCamel(str: string): string {
    return str.replace(/_([a-z])/g, (_, group1) => group1.toUpperCase());
}

function convertKeysToCamelCase(obj: Record<string, any>): Record<string, any> {
    const result: Record<string, any> = {};

    for (const key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            const camelKey = snakeToCamel(key);
            result[camelKey] = obj[key];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

You could also use the 'class-transformer' module (recomended):

```
npm i class-transformer
```

Then adapt your code like this:

```
import { Expose } from "class-transformer"
export class ChatHubInfo {
    @Expose({name: "hub_url"})
    hubUrl: string = undefined!
    
    /*...etc...*/
}
```

And then use the plainToClass function provided by the class-transformer module to generate the Object with the JSON-response:

```
import { plainToClass } from "class-transformer"
const chatHubInfo = plainToClass(ChatHubInfo, {
    "hub_url": "https://localhost:8080/",
    "access_token": "v4.public.eY..."
});
```